# Android Studio, delete all logs quickly from project

Tags: java, android, logging

When I work with big project I often use logs in development branch. But I don't want to have logs in release/master branches. When I am doing some card I use 10-50 logs depending on the difficulty of the task.
It takes 2-5 min to delete 50 logs in different classes. It's not a lot compared with a time of fulfilling of a task but I want to reduce this time.

For example I have logs like this:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Method: constantScrolling");
```

....

```
Log.d(TAG, "constantScrolling 2609 scrollTimer.cancel");
```

They all have the same beginning - Log.d(TAG

To find all logs to delete I use this: in java class <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> -> insert Log.d(TAG -> press arrow down -> press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> on every log.
So, I quickly delete all logs which having the same beginning Log.d(TAG

Is there a way to do that quicker? 
For example if there are some equal strings to delete I can use: right click on app -> Replace in path.. -> Text to find: Log.d(TAG, "Method: constantScrolling"); -> Replace with: (empty) -> Find
So, in some seconds I can delete equal strings on whole project.
Maybe there is some combination for deleting strings that having the same beginning?

Comment: Couldn't you leave the log statements in the code and configure the logging framework to not emit debug level logs?  The ability to configure different logging parameters in production and testing is one of the major features in almost every logging framework.

Answer (score 3):

my Way:

**1)** enable Column Selection Mode (`alt+shift+insert`)

**2)** select on one LOG.d(TAG, "text"); the part 'LOG.'

**3)** then do `shift + ctrl + alt + j`

**4)** click left arrow

**5)** do shift+end

**6)** hit delete.

this removes all LOG calls at once in a java file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ProGuard to delete logs when building for release. Simply add the following to your `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int d(...);
}
```

This will remove the logs when you're building for release. Obviously, make sure you have proguard on for release and off for debug. Also, this will keep your error logs in the app, cause you probably want those there anyway.

Comment: Thanks for advise but I need a another thing: I do some card in some branch, and then I merge it to common branch, usually in dev or release or master branch, and I don't want that logs go from some feature_branch to common branch.

Answer (score 1):

Press

```
ctrl+shift+r
```

Then enable Regex button in the opned window, its like

> .*

Write

```
Log.[edivw]\(.*;
```

In the first textbox

And be sure the second textbook is empty, then press replace all

*But recommend just replace Log. with //Log.
By this you just comment all logs.

Answer (score -1):

I would do that:

1. Right click on app
2. Replace in path
3. Find : "Log.d(" (or whatever you need)
4. Replace with : ""
5. Find

Comment: It doesn't work because replacing delete only beginning of the log. For example if I will do as you wrote and replace this "Log.d", in result will be end of logs:
before replacing
Log.d(TAG, "Method: constantScrolling");
after
(TAG, "Method: constantScrolling");
And it's not good. It's not delete log but only reduce it and make error.

Answer (score -1):

I'll give the Java equivalent of something I've done in C++:

```
class MyLog {
    static int d( String t, String m ) { return Log.d(t,m); }
    // static int d( String t, String m) { return 0; }
    static dx( String t, String m ) { return 0; }

    static int v( String t, String m ) { return Log.d(t,m); }
    // static int v( String t, String m) { return 0; }
    static vx( String t, String m ) { return 0; }

    ...
}
```

In my program I use:

MyLog.d( TAG, "Message" );

Now if I want to disable logging entirely, then I can go to the MyLog class and simply comment out the first (real) entry, and uncomment the dummy line. If I want to disable a specific entry, then change ".d" to ".dx" and the log entry stays in the source in case I want to enable it later.